# Which design pattern belongs to my project?

Tags: wcf, design-patterns

Hi
we have used the WCF service in my project. In our application the following layers are exists,

1. UI (aspx file), and code behind.
   (Customer.aspx)
2. UI entity Model (CustomerModel.cs)
   which is properties of the customer
   details.
3. UI layer calls the Business Façade class with the CustomerModel object.
4. In Business façade I have referenced the WCF service.
5. Convert the CustomerModel to CustomerContract.
6. Call the CustomerService from business façade.
7. In the service, I have convert CustomerContract into CustomerBO and call the CustomerBO class.
8. In the CustomerBO class,I have initialized the provider object and call the customer Provider class.
9. In Provider class, I have access the Database and send data from 8 to 1 layer.

I don't know which design pattern is using in our project. Can anybody help on this to identify design pattern.

Thanks

Comment: I'd advise against looking for patterns to batter your design with. You'll recognise the patterns when you come up with the design.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about design pattern but about architecture. Your architecture itself is not bad but it is really complex so unless you are creating very big project this architecture can be overkill. Moreover your naming of different layers is not correct. What you call BusinessFacade is usually called ServiceAgent. BusinessFacade should be placed on service site and wrapped by WCF service. Usual responsibility of BusinessFacade is to aggregate several business operations into single calls = create less granular API which can be easily and effectively exposed for remote calls.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. It helps to understand.